# Bootcamp on an external SSD while unintentional interrupt!

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, ssd

I'm a new Mac user and I wonder what really happens when my external SSD (with Windows installed on it using Bootcamp = Windows To Go) is disconnected while being booted to Windows.

Will my Mac system get damaged or will the files on my external SSD get corrupted?

Comment: Did you install Windows to Go or did you install Windows on an external disk? There is a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder what really happens when my external SSD (with Windows
>   installed on it using Bootcamp = Windows To Go) is disconnected while
>   being booted to Windows.

What happens is the exact same thing if you disconnect an internal drive while booting - you *potentially* corrupt your system files crashing that boot volume.

Since you have an internal drive that you *didn't* boot from, it wouldn't be affected.

Wondering (curiosity) is good.  Set up a test (don't do with live data or a machine you depend on) and test out your scenario.

Comment: Using a modern file system (with journaling/copy-on-write etc.) corruption shouldn't be severe and more important: the fs should be reparable. The file systems of the internal ssd are more or less protected because they are either not mounted or mounted read-only (if no HFS+/APFS r/w tools are installed in Windows).